How can I determine which parts of the skeletal mesh should be sliced?
I am currently trying to replicate skeletal mesh slicing, akin to something Metal Gear Rising: Revengeance did. So far I've managed to successfuly get some puzzle pieces of this whole thing together, like creating a new skeletal mesh out of some vertices, creating a new physics asset at runtime etc. My problem occurs in the slicing logic itself, though. I've currently mostly copied Unreal's built-in UKismetProceduralMeshLibrary::SliceProceduralMesh function, changing the data types and logic to fit a skeletal mesh. However, I am aware of the fact that this function does not check whether the two sliced pieces of geometry form a contiguous region. The function simply checks vertices above and below the slice plane and adds them to one or the other side of the slice. This could result in me cutting through a character's arm, and ending up with a floating piece of the lower arm invisibly attached to the character's lower body. I obviously do not want this, but I have serious trouble figuring out which parts of the mesh should stay together and which ones should not.
Something I had in mind was to use the skeletal hierarchy to do that, but I run into this issue:

If the plane is relatively perpendicular to the bone, I could technically consider just this bone, maybe its parent or children for the above/below plane logic. However, this doesn't work for case 2
If the plane is relatively parallel to the bone, the previous approach won't work in the case of me, say, performing a vertical slice through the head, since then I need to actually consider the entire body of the mesh.

It feels like these two scenarios and the solutions to them would be mutually exclusive, as there could be many edge cases, too e.g. "what if the character's hand is positioned in such a way that a slice will be considered vertical? This would result in a full-body cut despite me only wanting to cut the hand".
I tried thinking of a way to use vertex adjacency lists, but again, the criteria to determine what should stay on one or the other side can't be just "above/below the slicing plane", since I'll end up visually with three disjoint pieces of the character, two of them being invisibly connected and dependent on each other (and besides, It would feel weird that cutting an arm would result in the character's whole legs to be cut off).
I also thought of performing a trace from the hit bone (and checking if we hit a parent/child bone) to determine which bones should be considered for "above/below" logic, perhaps adjusting the trace length depending on the angle between the slice and the bone, but that leaves me with a problem of actually determining how long the trace should be for this to work.
Since I want to implement this in VR, I know I must achieve somewhat acceptable precision for this feature. Any help or push in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

Welcome, and thank you for a great question.
